# How do I include an external PHP file in a subdir Wordpress install?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, http

I have a Wordpress installation in directory /blog.

I am trying to include multiple PHP files located in the root parent directory using relative paths such as "../../include/file.php".

Since Wordpress uses its install directory as the base, I tried to change it by including

```
<base href="http://mydomain.com" />
```

inside of the head, but it had no effect.

What can I do appropriately call these PHP files in my Wordpress theme?

Comment: PHP couldn't care less about `<base`> tags. PHP operates on the server, and deals directly with the filesystem. `<base>` is for the client-side browser, telling it where to "base" its relative URLs in html

Comment: I'll add that to the things I've learned from this experience. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: While this is a PHP vs HTML and URL vs File system question, it would be better if WordPress questions are posted on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll be sure to do that in the future.

Comment: can you move the files to a wordpress subdirectory `( preferably wp-content/myfolder )` then including would be easy

Answer (score 1):

you can try put this in `wp-config`

```
$rootpath = explode( basename( dirname(__FILE__) ), ABSPATH ); 
define( 'MYROOT', $rootpath[0] );
```

And then, for anyfile in the root directory :

```
include( MYROOT . 'somefile.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try such hack for file in parent directory:

```
$path =  dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/some_file.php';
```